# Firebase OAuth2 signInWithRedirect() occasionally infinite loop, but not always

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

I am using google firebase 11.4.2 with React 18.2.0
I have implemented Google and Yahoo OAuth2 login on my app using firebase's authentication methods.

My problem is that only with certain users, about 1/10, experience being redirected to select the Oauth login page, an infinite loop according to other similarly posted problems.

---

I have two questions: Why are only certain users having this issue, and the second question is: where in my code am I going wrong with the proper order of operations. The order of my code is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
        redirResults();
}, [])

const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // there are Google & Yahoo buttons for the user to click/choose
        let authP = e.target.name
        
        try {
            switch(authP) {
                case "google":
                    await signInWithRedirect(auth, gProvider)
                    break;
                case "yahoo":
                    await signInWithRedirect(auth, yProvider)
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log('Error, try again.')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }

const redirResults = async () => {
        
        await getRedirectResult(auth)
            .then((result) => {
                const user = result.user;
                
                if (result) {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Loading...',
                        timer: 1000,
                        didOpen: () => {
                            Swal.showLoading()
                        }
                    })
                }
                // sets my user object internally
                dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', payload: user })
                // checking for existing account, if not one, 
                // automatically make one based 
                // on the users OAuth data
                checkForExistingUser(user);
                
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //  console.log(error.code)
                //  console.log(error.message)
                //  console.log(error.customData?.email)
            })
    }

const checkForExistingUser = async (user) => {
        
        const userRef = doc(db, 'users', user.uid)
        const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef)

        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            console.log('already exists!!!!!!');
            navigate('/dashboard')
        } else {
            // console.log('doesnt exist yet');
            await setDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid), {
                email: user.email,
                emailVerified: true,
                img: user.photoURL || '',
                timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
                username: user.displayName || '',
            })
            navigate('/dashboard')
        }
    }
```

Please advise if there is more information that you need to help me come to a conclusion. Thanks in advance to everyone for their help, as always. 
Cheers~

Comment: Please add where you are calling this code, especially the code that renders `/dashboard`. It is likely that you are doing something like `if (!user) navigate("/login")` before the authentication state has been determined. Additionally, you should open your browser's DevTools and activate the "Preserve log" setting. This will allow you to see any errors that are being thrown just before a `navigate()` call.

Comment: @samthecodingman all of this code is in one component, oauth.js
The code listed is in order of call sequence from the top down, not in the order that I wrote each function.
1st: User clicks Google Oauth or Yahoo Oauth button which triggers the switch in handleLogin(), which then calls signInWithRedirect(), passing the args firebase.auth() and the selected provider.
2nd: redirResults() fires calling firebase getRedirectResults(auth) passing the auth.
3rd: checkForExistingUser() fires off, if the user exists it forwards them, if they dont, it builds a new user profile.
Does that help?

Comment: I will enable the "preserve log" setting in the dev tools, but one issue I have is that I have been unsuccessful in replicating the problem myself, with multiple browsers even.